# Obtener la vista raíz (rootview) de la actividad actual en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Cómo se puede obtener el identificar de la raíz de un layout, es decir si el elemento de apertura de la estructura del layout no le asignamos ningún identificador, en java se puede acceder a el?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtenido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity)
Si se necesita acceder a la vista raíz del layout se puede

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

O bien:

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Una opción para obtener la vista raíz es :

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```