# ¿Como hacer un Snackbar multilinea?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un formulario donde se recoge un texto y la idea es que se debe mostrar en un snackbar (Requisitos del ejercicio).
Mi problema es que el texto me lo corta, he buscado en google y aquí pero lo que encuentro no me vale

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String mensaje = "Los datos introducidos son: \n"+
                et1.getText()+et2.getText()+"\n"+et3.getText()+"\n"+et4.getText()+"\n"+et5.getText();
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mi1:
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(tv1,""+mensaje, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById((android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setMaxLines(5);
                snackbar.show();
                return true;
```

El problema es que el design de esta linea

```
TextView textView = snackbarView.findViewById((android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
```

no me lo admite, me dice no puede resolver el símbolo

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que funicone y os lo dejo por si alguien se encuentra el mismo problema

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            String mensaje = "Los datos introducidos son: \n"+ et1.getText()+et2.getText()+"\n"+
            et3.getText()+"\n"+et4.getText()+"\n"+et5.getText();
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.mi1:
                    View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, mensaje, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = layout.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(20);
                    snackbar.show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.mi2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Para generar un `SnackBar` necesitas la "vista raiz" que es donde se mostraría esta vista. Esto lo puedes obtener mediante:

```
 ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

o mediante:

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Obtener la vista raíz (rootview) de la actividad actual en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/obtener-la-vista-ra%c3%adz-rootview-de-la-actividad-actual-en-android)

Ahora de esta forma puedes generar tu `SnackBar` multilinea, obteniendo el TextView del Snackbar y definiendo la propiedad `setMaxLines()` , ejemplo:

```
 String mensaje = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.";

 ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, mensaje, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
 TextView textView = snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
 textView.setMaxLines(20);
 snackbar.show();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Muy importante, cuando migres tu proyecto a `AndroidX`, para obtener la referencia del `TextView` dentro del `SnackBar`, se tendrá que realizar de esta forma:

```
 TextView textView = snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
```